# AngularJS Blocked loading resource

Tags: angularjs

I am not sure why but I am trying to make an image button and the URL's come from getting a JSON object in my controller, but what ever the link is through an error, and if I change it to  works fine!!!

Controller:

```
$scope.iconImage = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png';
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy. -->
<input type="image" ng-src="{{iconImage}}" />

<!-- This works fine -->
<img ng-src="{{iconImage}}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use the Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) mode to marked the URL as a safe content source.

See [trustAsResourceUrl(value);](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsResourceUrl)

Inject [$sce] in your controller and then use it like this:

```
$scope.iconImage = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png');
```

Comment: That's right. Just to add that using ngSrc for img tag is an exception from Strict Contextual Escaping, that's why it works for `<img ng-src="{{iconImage}}" />`.

Answer (score 0):

You can white list the URL using the `$sceDelegateProvider`. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider).